# How to iterate over a HashMap while avoiding ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, collections, concurrentmodification

I have a HashMap, its of the type `HashMap<String,HashMap<String,int>>` now i need to iterate over this HashMap and delete the inner HashMaps that have a value of 0 for any key.

If such a removal makes the inner HashMap empty then the inner HashMap's corresponding key is removed from the outer HashMap. I tried iterating over it and then removing elements that match the requirements, but that throws me a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

I tried the following code:

```
synchronized(MyConstants.cliListUpdateList)
{
    synchronized(MyConstants.cliList)
    {
        outerEntries = MyConstants.cliListUpdateList.entrySet();
        outerIterator = outerEntries.iterator();

        while(outerIterator.hasNext())
        {
            outerEnt = (Entry) outerIterator.next();
            innerHashMap = (HashMap) outerEnt.getValue();
            synchronized(innerHashMap)
            {//synchronize innerhashmap
            innerEntries = innerHashMap.entrySet();
            innerIterator = innerEntries.iterator();
            synchronized(innerIterator)
            {
            while(innerIterator.hasNext())
            {
                innerEnt = (Entry) innerIterator.next();
                int k = Integer.parseInt((String)innerEnt.getValue());
                if(k==0)
                {
                    innerHashMap.remove(innerEnt.getKey());
                    if(innerHashMap.isEmpty())
                    {
                        MyConstants.cliListUpdateList.remove(outerEnt.getKey());
                    }

                    ArrayList ports = (ArrayList) MyConstants.cliList.get(outerEnt.getKey());
                    ports.remove((String)innerEnt.getKey());
                    if(ports.isEmpty())
                    {
                        MyConstants.cliList.remove(outerEnt.getKey());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    k--;
                    innerHashMap.put(innerEnt.getKey(), k+"");
                    MyConstants.cliListUpdateList.put(outerEnt.getKey(), innerHashMap);
                }

            }
            }
        }//synchronize innerhashmap
        }


        System.out.println(MyConstants.cliListUpdateList + " <---> "+ MyConstants.cliList);

    }
}
```

I am getting the exception at this line: `innerEnt = (Entry) innerIterator.next();`. I tried the remove method provided by the Iterator class. But that is also no good.

**EDIT**

from the Java docs I know this much `if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this(ConcurrentModificationException) exception` but I need exactly the same functionality.

Comment: I tried as many synchronized blocks as possible, but no good :(

Comment: Synchronization won't save you because this is all being caused by a single thread. Synchronization is used to serialize operations performed by multiple threads against a single non-thread-safe container such as `HashMap`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May not solve your problem completely but instead of `innerHashMap.remove(innerEnt.getKey());` you need to use the iterator's remove method `innerIterator.remove();`

Comment: Exactly, the iterator is designed to allow removal of the current key/value pair while keeping the iterator in tact. The docs for `entrySet` specifically say that removal via `remove` is acceptable. Are you sure you've changed all removals to use the appropriate iterator?

Comment: In addition to the above, use `Map.Entry.setValue` instead of `put` to decrement the counter in the inner maps. The docs suggest that using `put` should be okay, but try this.

Comment: @DavidHarkness my bad, my bad. I over looked a HashMap.remove method. All is good and working now. thank you. Thanks for the advice too.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using Synchronized Hashmap ? `Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap())` or take a look at [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

Comment: from the java docs I know this much `if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this(ConcurrentModificationException) exception` but i need exactly the same functionality :(